# Should days of week be in plural form?

Tags: time, adverbial-phrases

Are these sentences natural?

> 1. Members of my family have their weddings on Saturdays.
> 2. Pete pays a visit to his grandmother once a month. He does it on Saturdays.
> 3. I celebrate my birthday on Saturdays.

It is obvious that 'Saturdays' doesn't mean 'every Saturday' or 'almost every Saturday'. But are the sentences natural? Would you consider them incorrect? Or awkward?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are phrasing your sentences, they are a bit awkward.

> Pete pays a visit to his grandmother once a month. He does it on **a** Saturday.

"***Saturday***" should be singular, since he only does it **once** a month. Otherwise,

> Pete pays a visit to his grandmother once a week. He does it on **Saturdays**.

Your other sentences

> Members of my family have their weddings on Saturdays.
>   I celebrate my birthday on Saturdays.

would be understood to mean

> Members of my family have their weddings on **a** Saturday.
>   I celebrate my birthday on **a** Saturday.

Answer (score 1):

Your first and third sentences sound natural to me. I'm not sure what I think of your second, but I would probably say "Pete pays a visit to his grandmother once a month, always on a Saturday."