# Friday afternoons always drag. vs Friday afternoon always drags

Tags: phrase-usage

> Friday afternoons always drag.

Is it possible to write "Friday afternoon always drags." if we say about it in general, or not?
In my native language we use this phrase only in singular form. Do you use only plural form for this phrase? If it is so, explain this rule in detail, please.

Comment: See: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/163029/should-days-of-week-be-in-plural-form https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79086/articles-with-the-days-of-the-week-is-it-a-monday-today/79087#79087 Yes, days of the week are often used in the plural if we mean, for instance, "every Friday": "I have piano lessons *on Fridays*." But also, yes, the singular example you gave is just fine too.

Comment: @Andy Bonner OK, thanks for your quick answer.